How to use nginx to fetch the environment variables
How do I pick the values of the env variables which i am fetching from the secrets (defined in the pipeline) during the deployment in my frontend which uses javascript. I have a docker container running Nginx.
I got to know that we can replace the variables with values through nginx.conf.
nginx docker image already runs envsubst and the pipeline i am using is already picking the secrets ,but i am not sure how i use them in nginx.conf and after picking how do i substitute in the .js files where it is referencing.
Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
